# What value for recall implies a logistic regression model is good?

Tags: regression, logistic, model-evaluation, precision-recall

I'm studying logistic regression using Python and about metrics to have a good model, I know this three: accuracy, precision and recall. In the same way, I was studying using a dataset about ads in social networks using the feature `Year` (years old of the customer) to estimate if these customers will purchase the advertised product. So, at the end my model's metrics were:

```
Accuracy:  0.9375
Precision: 0.9473684210526315
Recall:    0.8181818181818182
```

Are these good metrics for my model?

Comment: Here is a controversial idea: models are not good or bad in their own right, but only in comparison to other potential models.

Comment: Tempting as it is to say that a $80\%$ is an $\text{B}$ in school so you must be doing reasonably well, it's impossible to say without knowing more about the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "golden rule" when it comes to anything related to ML, models and metrics. A common approach is to build a [simple classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.dummy.DummyClassifier.html)
and use it to compare against more advanced models. IMO every single metric should be understood in context. Perhaps "65% accuracy" might seem low, but if the baseline model is offering, say, 55%, that extra 10% gain could mean millions of dollars saved, or lifes, depending on the context. And that applies to all metrics. And keep in mind that most metrics are sensitive to the classification threshold you set (i.e, what's the probability you conssider for each class, default = 0.5)